# django: I accidentally deleted the manage.py file. how to recover it?

Tags: django, nerdtree, manage.py

I accidentally deleted the manage.py file with vim nerdtree. apparently, there isn't a way to recover it I I don't know what to do.

can I somehow create a new one or restore it?

Comment: probably `git` ?

Comment: *Hopefully* `git`…?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: can I create another project and copy its manage.py file?

Comment: That's what I'd do, yes. And start to use git.

Comment: If you didn't change anything in manage.py file than just create a new project and copy the file to the current project, otherwise if you edit it, the repo is the only hope

Comment: yes. I should use git after this terrible trouble.

Comment: so I create another project and copy its manage.py file. ok thank you so so much

Answer (score 1):

You can easily copy this file by changing the "start.settings" with your "application.settings". The other codes is always the same :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

def main():
   os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'starter.settings')
   try:
      from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
   except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Django project by using the following command:

```
django-admin startproject someappname
```

and copy the file into your project and **ensure to change the app name on the manage.py file**